# Is there a performance difference between Model First and Code First in MS Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm starting a new development and I plan to use Code First in Entity Framework 4.1.

I have previously used Model First and found some performance issues around loading context, first calls to SaveChanges() and where Association Fix-up kicks in.

Has anyone compared performance of these two techniques - or, at the end of the day are they insignificant?

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience Code-first is actually slower than Model-first (or rather, database-first). But it ultimately doesn't matter, because you can switch ORM provider later. What bugs me with CF approach, is that if your database is complex enough, you'd end up wanting to update it, and there's no mechanism to augment databases - even if you are adding completely irrelevant columns.

Comment: Thanks Gleno. I suspect that any performance difference is negligible - just wanted to hear back on any hands-on experience. In general (MF and CF), EF is poor at handling schema updates (dropping and recreating the db is hardly elegant) though there are ways to extract the changes. I certainly avoid the fix-up code where I can - this can be a nightmare.

Comment: Isn't Model-First just a *design-time* strategy? In the end you create model classes and a DbContext from a T4 template. At *runtime* it doesn't matter if you have hand-written those classes (code-first) or if they were autogenerated from a design tool (model-first).

Comment: @Slauma @Ladislav. Thanks I was not sure. I found an article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148150.aspx where it states "Whichever modeling technique you choose—Database First, Model First or Code First—once you’ve created a model, you won’t notice any difference when you begin to query, interact with and persist entities using the Entity Framework runtime by way of the model’s classes". So that's pretty clear then. Thanks guys.

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer and expanded a bit.

Comment: @Slauma, @Ladislav - If you end up using the design-time POCOs, isn't there a runtime performance hit because of all the virtual-property reflection magic? Oh, not to mention the extra model verification checks that I can only assume fire each time you init a new DbContext, which is supposed to be cheap. As I said already, you can of course change the ORM provider to whatever you want, after you've created your model. But that's not the philosophy of Code First approach as I see it. Coupled with the fact that CF is not suitable for database augmentation, I do feel need to warn with large type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that there is no difference at all in performance. Code-First, Model-First, Database-First are modelling strategies at **design time**. For both Model-First and Database-First entity classes and a `DbContext` will be created with a T4 template. At **runtime** EF 4.1 just works with those classes and it doesn't matter where they come from - hand-written (Code-First) or autogenerated from the T4 template (Model-First, Database-First).

Also keep in mind that the benefit that Model-First gives you is rather limited in my opinion: You just have the possibility to create your model classes on a design surface in VS2010. But there are more drawbacks on the other side: The *default* T4 template isn't very fine granular in creating the code from the model. For instance: It doesn't put `MaxLength` attributes on the properties, it creates always navigation properties on both sides on a relationship (you often don't want and need both sides) and the overridden `OnModelCreating` method in `DbContext` just contains the single line `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` which isn't particularly impressive. You can modify the template and the CSDL part of the EDMX file though to achieve more granularity when the model classes and the DbContext are generated (thanks to Ladislav for his comment below about this option).

In other words it is very likely that you have to tweak the generated code (adding attributes, removing unwished navigation properties, adding Fluent mapping code and so on) in order to get the finetuned model classes you want to work with. As soon as you have done this it becomes difficult to do any changes in the model designer because the DbContext generator will overwrite all your hand-made changes in the code.

In my opinion Model-First with EF 4.1 is only useful if you already have a model designed in the designer surface for instance from an older EF 4.0 project and you want to migrate your project to EF 4.1 In this case the DbContext generator might be useful to create *initial* code for you. From that point I would proceed with working in the code alone which means: Working with Code-First. If you start with a new project I would prefer Code-First from the beginning. Even if you really want or need this visual representation of the model in the designer surface also in Code-First you can simply create an EDMX file from your DbContext and open it in VS2010 to show your model classes and their relationships in the designer:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\MyModel.edmx", Encoding.Default))
    {
        EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(context, writer);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

There is actually one point where EF 4.1 recogizes the difference whether a model comes from Model-First (i.e. an EDMX model file and designer surface) or if it is a pure Code-First model - and that is the connection string. If you create a model from Model-First you get a connection string which contains references to the model metadata files, like so:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl
         |res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;
         initial catalog=MyDb;integrated security=True;
         multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Whereas for Code-First simply a "normal" connection string without metadata references is used:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now you can use the second simple connection string without problems also for a model which is created via Model-First. But the code snippet above (creating an EDMX from DbContext) throws an exception with the first connection string telling that `WriteEdmx` can only be used with Code-First but not Model-First or Database-First. So obviously the DbContext processes or stores somehow the metadata information from the connection string.

How to interprete this? Does it mean that it actually uses the data in the EDMX file specified in the connection string when the model is built in memory? In this case there could theoretically be a performance difference between Code-First and Model-First (at least at model-build-time). But I don't think that the metadata are actually processed. But the mentioned exception is somewhat weird. Why does EF 4.1 prevent me to create an EDMX model file when my model comes from Model-First? Perhaps just to avoid possible confusion and mess with two EDMX files? I don't know.

Comment: +1, but I think you miss a bit of magic that Code-First POCOs go through at runtime. Compared to actual networking delays this magic is obviously cheap, but the model also has to be verified against a database-stored checksum, which obviously incurs additional processing and networking costs. But, as most people, I can live with that, because it saves on developer time. But since CF encourages you to use these POCOs, you might get stuck when you want to update your table definitions later (ex. shipped product, add table, change checksum, break product).

Comment: @Gleno: Model is validated only once when the context is used for the first time after the application is started. Moreover that feature can be turned off.

Comment: @Slauma: Even with model first you can get any granularity you want and you can add data annotations you want but it requires some changes in T4 template and most of the time some manual changes in CSDL part of XML (structural annotations).

Comment: @Ladislav: I see, I hadn't modification of the template and EDMX in mind. I've added a note about this into my answer.

Comment: @Sluama @Gleno @Ladislav Thanks all for very useful comments. I was not aware of the EdmxWriter so that's interesting. I would like to use T4 templates simply to increase productivity so having the EDMX file is important.

Comment: My experience in a high transaction environment was some performance degradation after converting to Code First. It was not severe but maybe around 2% but still that sux and am investigating how to get the performance back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are performance differences between Model First (EF 4.0) and Code First (EF 4.1 - 4.3.1):

- You cannot [pre-generate internal query views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx). This means that every time EF tries to run its first query (per app domain), it will need to perform an expensive operation to generate those views, depending on your model complexity. This usually affects application startup performance and can make debugging quite annoying.
- You cannot use [compiled queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx). This can seriously affect queries that are used often, especially complex queries. It can become a serious bottleneck and a CPU hog. Only EF 5.0 (that will be included with .NET 4.5) fixes this issue by automatically compiling all queries, including Code First queries.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this benshmark](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/05/yet-another-orm-micro-benchmark-part-23_15.html) **yes**. It says also that **EF Model First is always faster than EF Code First.**