# Model First Or Code First for Large Databse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need your opinion. I am using a Model First Approach in my ASP MVC Application by Efw 6.1. There is too many tables(Approx 200) in a database and it is very hard for me to write code for it because of time limits.

Is there any Performance Issue When Model first technique is used for any Large Database Application instead of Code First?

Comment: DId you put any effort to do some google?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a performance difference between Model First and Code First in MS Entity Framework 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717042/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-model-first-and-code-first-in-ms-entit)

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee I mention The Entity Framework 6.1

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio

1. In Solution Explorer
2. Right click on project
3. Entity Framework - Reverse engenerieng

VS create

a) Context

b) all models

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any performance issues when using eighter one. Use the one you feel the most comfortable with.

Model first is great, go for it.

[Long answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720006/2247996)

Comment: If you find a duplicate, you should mark the question as so

Answer (score 2):

To define a model in EF you can use Code First or a "graphic" Model where you can draw tables and relationships. Please note that:

- there are tools to reverse engineer a DB to both kind of models, Model, or Code First
- independently form being Code First or Model, internally, there is always an EDM in memory and it's exactle the same (or have very slight differences)

So, the time that takes to create a Model or a Code First model is the same. You should think if you'll feel more comfortable with one or the other when it comes to maintaining the model.

If your model will evolve, in Code First you can use Migrations. In the other case you have direct "right click" options to apply the model changes to the database. Migrations give you more control on the database upgrade (or even downgrade) process, and they can be easyly applied to the development DB but also to any other DB (production, staging...).

If you are worried about performance, as I told both models are similar in memory. And one of the most time consuming tasks, which is creating the views, will take the same time in both cases. This happens when you app starts and a context is used for the first time. But you can use the [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to pre-create this views (don't worry about it being a Beta 4, you can safely use. I've been using this tool for years).

As you can see in the link to the EF Power Tool, it adds interesting options to your menu, but I was speaking about creating Views. You can use it both for Code First or Model.

Finally, if you use Code First you can create several different Contexts, each of which has only part of the tables. This improves the performane, if it's really a problem for you.

So the decision should be based upon your personal preferences and the way you work. If you have no preferences, I'd recommend using Code First, updating the entities in code, and apply the changes to the DB using Migrations. Think that a very big Model with lots of entities an relations can be difficutl to navigate and see. In Code First you can always find an entity (class) by names, or organize the entities in several different files.

As a final note, most of what can be done with a Model, can also be done with Code First. Unless you're going to do something very specific, I doubt that's a reason to choose one or the other.

Comment: I've found migrations to be a right pain to handle, especially if you have frequent design changes (as is likely in pre-alpha versions). Personally, I wouldn't recommend code-first for a large dataset unless you have an awful lot of faith in your data architecture plan.

Comment: That's surprising. Besides, you can always delete the migrations and start from scratch if you need to, or re-create a Code First model by reverse engineering your DB. In this case I suppose a model with 200 tables should be somewhat stable and Migrations will help to evolve it. It give more control that the "Update database" of a edmx model. With Migrations you can create an script for the updates, and review it, and even modify it adding some steps to the migration. That makes it very easy to move changes from development to production as the model evolves. In edmx model that can't be done

Comment: @MattThrower What do you use to handle those frequent changes? What's your way of working?

Comment: My way of working is to use DB-first :) I also find I can visualise relationships more easily via SQL than .Net collections, but that's a personal thing. You make a good point that a 200-table system has probably already been heavily tested for stability.